# Writing $A: \mathcal H\to \mathcal H$ as matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}W & X\\ Y& Z \end{matrix}\right]$ with operator entries w.r.t. $M\le \mathcal H$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Pg. $38$, Chapter $2$, *Operators on Hilbert Space* of J.B. Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis* defines a certain matrix notation for operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. The $2\times 2$ matrix with operator entries is constructed with respect to a closed subspace $M$ of $H$, which the author denotes as $M \le H$. I need help understanding this concept, as the author has not provided any examples, or explained how the matrix entries are obtained from the original operator.

> If $M\le H$, then $H  =M\oplus M^\perp$. If $A\in B(\mathcal H)$, then $A$ can be written as a $2\times 2$ matrix with operator entries, $$A = \left[\begin{matrix}W & X\\ Y& Z \end{matrix}\right]$$
> where $W:M\to M$, $X: M^\perp \to M$, $Y: M\to M^\perp$ and $Z: M^\perp\to M^\perp$ are bounded linear maps.

Note that $B(\mathcal H)$ refers to the algebra of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal H$.

**Questions:**

1. Given $A$, how does one obtain $W,X,Y$ and $Z$? What do these matrix entries say about the original operator $A$?
2. Given $h\in \mathcal H$, can I use this matrix representation to find $Ah$? As $\mathcal H = M\oplus M^\perp$, there exist unique $h_1 \in M$ and $h_2 \in M^\perp$ with $h = h_1+h_2$. Is it true that $$Ah = \left[\begin{matrix}W & X\\ Y& Z \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}h_1\\ h_2 \end{matrix}\right]$$
3. Given some other operator $$A' = \left[\begin{matrix}W' & X'\\ Y'& Z' \end{matrix}\right]$$
   does it make sense to write $$AA' = \left[\begin{matrix}W & X\\ Y& Z \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}W' & X'\\ Y'& Z' \end{matrix}\right]$$

I believe all my questions stem from a lack of understanding of how this *decomposition* arises in the first place, and *what the matrix entries $W,X,Y,Z$ really say about the operator $A$.* I would appreciate any explanations (and possibly examples) that would increase my understanding of this concept. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $M$. Then
$$
W=PAP,\quad X=PA(1-P),\quad Y=(1-P)AP,\quad Z=(1-P)A(1-P). 
$$
Properly, one is also taking the restriction, i.e. $W=PA|_M$, $X=PA_{M^\perp}$, etc. But other than notationally, the distinction is most often unnecessary.

It is trivial to check that $A=W+X+Y+Z$.

If $h=h_1+h_2$, with $h_1=Ph$, $h_2=(1-P)h$, then $Xh_1=Zh_1=0$, $Yh_2$, $Wh_2=0$, so
$$
Ah=(Xh_1+Wh_2)+(Yh_1+Zh_2)=\begin{bmatrix}W&X\\ Y&Z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}h_1\\ h_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
when you think of $h$ as $\begin{bmatrix} h_1\\ h_2\end{bmatrix}$.

Same kind of reasoning can be applied to see that the product behaves like the product of matrices.

Comment: You say that $W = PAP$, but then you say that $W = PA\vert_M$? Is this a typo or am I missing something? Does $PA\vert_M$ mean "project onto $M$ first, then multiply by $PA$"?

Comment: It's the universal/standard notation for the [restriction of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)).

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this notation. Would you say that $W = PA\vert_M$, $X = PA\vert_{M^\perp}$, $Y = (1-P)A\vert_M$ and $Z = (1-P)A\vert_{M^\perp}$?

Comment: Yes. But the difference between $PAP$ and $PA|_M$ is just that the domain of the first one is bigger; that is, $PA|_M$ is not defined on $M^\perp$ and $PAP$ is zero on $M^\perp$. There is not much to gain in emphasizing the distinction.