# Proof of the Spectral Theorem for Compact Normal Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am reading [*Invariant Subspaces* by H. Radjavi and P. Rosenthal.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65574-6) I need help understanding the proof of the spectral theorem for compact normal operators, as stated below.

> **Theorem $1.4.$** (Spectral Theorem for Compact Normal Operators).  If $A$ is a compact normal operator, then there exists an orthonormal basis $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ such that each $e_\alpha$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

I will reproduce the proof below, and ask questions simultaneously. Firstly, we are assuming $A\ne 0$, right?

> By Zorn's lemma there is a maximal orthonormal set $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

1. How is Zorn's lemma being applied here? I know that if $A \ne 0$ is compact and normal, then $\varnothing \ne \sigma(A)\setminus\{0\} = \sigma_p(A)\setminus\{0\}$ where $\sigma_p(A)$ is the point spectrum of $A$ (eigenvalues of $A$). So, there exists $\lambda\ne 0$ such that $\lambda\in \sigma_p(A)$. I believe we might have to do something with $E(\lambda):= \{x\in \mathcal H: Tx = \lambda x\}$, the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

> We need only show that $\bigvee_{\alpha\in I} e_\alpha = \mathcal H$. Let $M = \bigvee_{\alpha\in I} e_\alpha$. By Theorem $1.2$, the one-dimensional space spanned by $e_\alpha$ reduces $A$ for each $\alpha$, and therefore $M$ reduces $A$. If $M^\perp\ne \{0\}$, consider $A\vert_{M^\perp}$. The operator $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ is compact and normal.

2. I know that if $A$ is compact and $A = \left[\begin{matrix}W & X\\ Y& Z \end{matrix}\right]$, then each of $W,X,Y,Z$ are compact (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358257/writing-a-mathcal-h-to-mathcal-h-as-matrix-left-beginmatrixw-x-y) for details on matrix notation). So, $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ is compact. Why is $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ normal?

> If $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ were $0$, the set $\{e_\alpha\}$ would not be maximal.

3. I wish to verify my understanding of why $A\vert_{M^\perp} = 0$ is not permitted. We have $M^\perp \ne \{0\}$, and $A\vert_{M^\perp} = 0$ would mean that there exists $0\ne z\in M^\perp$ with $A\vert_{M^\perp} z = 0 = 0z$, i.e. $z$ is an eigenvector for $A\vert_{M^\perp}$. If $Az = 0$, then $Az = 0z$, i.e. $z\in M^\perp$ is an eigenvector for $A$, but this contradicts the maximality of $M$. The other possibility is that $Az \in M$. Why does this contradict the maximality of $M$?

> Thus, $\sigma\left(A\vert_{M^\perp} \right)$ contains a non-zero complex number, by Theorem $1.1$, and hence, by the Fredholm alternative, $\sigma_p\left(A\vert_{M^\perp} \right)$ is not empty. Thus, $A$ has an eigenvector in $M^\perp$, contradicting the maximality of $\{e_\alpha\}$.

4. Perhaps this is the same question as (3) above, but $\sigma_p\left(A\vert_{M^\perp} \right) \ne \varnothing$ means that $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ has an eigenvector in $M^\perp$. How does this imply that $A$ has an eigenvector in $M^\perp$?

---

*Notation.*

1. $\bigvee_{\alpha\in I} e_\alpha$ denotes the closed linear span of $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$, i.e. $\overline{\operatorname{span} \{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}}$.
2. $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ should be interpreted as the *compression* of $A$ to $M^\perp$, given by $M^\perp \xrightarrow{A} \mathcal H \xrightarrow{P_{M^\perp}} M^\perp$ where $P_{M^\perp}$ is the projection map onto $M^\perp$.

---

*Other Theorems.*

> **Theorem $1.1.$** If $A$ is normal, then $\|A\| = r(A)$ (the spectral radius of $A$). 
> **Theorem $1.2.$** If $A$ is normal and $Ax=\lambda x$, then $A^*x = \overline\lambda x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assume $A\neq 0$. If $A=0$, then any ONB of $\mathcal H$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$.

1. You don't need to know much about compact operators for this step. Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all orthonormal sets of eigenvectors of $A$, ordered by inclusion. Every chain in $\mathcal F$ has an upper bound, namely the union. Thus $\mathcal F$ has a maximal element by Zorn's lemma.
2. A reducing subspace for $A$ is also reducing for $A^\ast$. Thus $A^\ast(M^\perp)\subset M^\perp$ and you an check that $(A|_{M^\perp})^\ast=A^\ast|_{M^\perp}$, which clearly commutes with $A|_{M^\perp}$ by normality of $A$. Hence $A|_{M^\perp}$ is normal.
3. Since $z\in M^\perp$, you have $A|_{M^\perp}z=Az$. That is just the definition of the restriction of a map.
4. See 3. If $z\in M^\perp$ and $A|_{M^\perp}z=\lambda z$, then $Az=A|_{M^\perp}z=\lambda z$ by the definition of the restriction.

Comment: Please see (2) of the section on *Notation*. $A\vert_{M^\perp}$ is *compression*, not restriction. In view of that, you may need to revise your answer.

Comment: Call it whatever you want. If $M$ is a reducing subspace, then $A|_{M^\perp}$ is the restriction.

Comment: In the step that uses Zorn's lemma, it seems we don't need that there exists a non-zero eigenvalue (I guess we only need the existence of *some* eigenvalue; correct me if I am wrong) as I have shown?

Comment: You don't need the existence of any eigenvalue there. If $A$ had no eigenvectors, then $\mathcal F=\{\emptyset\}$, which certainly has a maximal element.

Comment: Makes sense. In that case, $M^\perp = \mathcal H$.

Comment: That's right. Of course we know that this cannot actually happen, as is used later.

Comment: Why can it not happen?

Comment: Ok, strictly speaking it can happen if $\mathcal H=\{0\}$. Otherwise either $A=0$, in which case every vector of norm one is an eigenvector, or $\sigma(A)$ contains a non-zero complex number, hence $\sigma_p(A)\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Could you also take a look at this very similar question? Thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377607/proof-of-the-spectral-theorem-for-normal-operators