# Proof of the Spectral Theorem for Normal Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am reading [*Invariant Subspaces* by H. Radjavi and P. Rosenthal.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65574-6) I need help understanding the proof of the spectral theorem for normal operators, as stated below.

> **Theorem**. If $A$ is a normal operator on a separable space, then there exists a finite measure space $(X,\mu)$ and $h\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ such that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to the operator
> $M_h$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$.

I will reproduce the proof here, and ask questions simultaneously. I understand the proof in the case where $A\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ has a cyclic vector $f$, i.e. $\bigvee_{m,n = 0}^\infty \{A^n(A^*)^m f\} = \mathcal H$, where $\bigvee$ denotes the *closed linear span*. So, let us move to the general case directly.

> **Proof.** Since for any $f\in \mathcal H$, $\bigvee_{m,n = 0}^\infty \{A^n(A^*)^m f\}$ reduces $A$, Zorn's lemma implies that there exists a collection $\{M_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of pairwise-orthogonal subspaces of $\mathcal H$ such that $\mathcal H = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_n$, each $M_n$ reduces $A$, and $A\vert_{M_n}$ has a cyclic vector for each $n$ (the fact that the collection is countable follows from separability of $\mathcal H$).

1. How exactly is Zorn's lemma being used here, to produce the required collection of subspaces? It would be helpful if someone could provide the details.

> By the cyclic case, for each $n$, there is a finite measure $\mu_n$ on $X_n:= \sigma(A\vert_{M_n})$ such that $A\vert_{M_n}$ is unitarily equivalent to $M_z$ on $L^2(X_n,\mu_n)$. We can assume $\mu_n(X_n) \le 2^{-n}$. Let $h_n(z) = z$ for all $z\in X_n$. Then, $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_{h_n}$ on the space $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty L^2(X_n,\mu_n)$. We must show how to regard $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty L^2(X_n,\mu_n)$ as $L^2(X,\mu)$ in such a way that $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_{h_n}$ is unitarily equivalent to $M_h$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$ for some $h$. Relabel the elements of the sets $\{X_n\}$ to make the sets pairwise disjoint, and then let $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$. Define the measurable subsets of $X$ as the subsets which are countable unions of measurable subsets of the $\{X_n\}$, and if $S = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is a measurable set with $S_n \subset X_n$ for every $n$, define $\mu(S) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_n(S_n)$. Then, $(X,\mu)$ is a finite measure space. If we define $h$ on $X$ by $h(x) = h_n(x)$ for all $x\in X_n$, then $h\in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ (in fact $\|h\|_\infty = \|A\|$).

2. How is $\|h\|_\infty = \|A\|$? I believe this has something to do with $\|T\| = r(T)$ (the spectral radius) for normal operators $T\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$.

> It is easily verified that $M_h$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$ is unitarily equivalent to $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_{h_n}$, and hence to $A$.

3. Could someone please help me with *explicit details* of the above verification? I'm confused primarily because $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_{h_n}$ is not an operator on $L^2(X,\mu)$, but on $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty L^2(X_n,\mu_n)$. I understand that we are identifying $L^2(X,\mu)$ and $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty L^2(X_n,\mu_n)$ using the recipe above; but I am not clear about how to proceed.

Thank you very much! Please let me know if any of the notations is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Consider the set $\{\oplus_{i\in I} M_i | M_i \text{ is cyclic and closed} \}$. Define the partial order $\oplus_{i\in I} M_i\le\oplus_{j\in J} M_j$ if for each $i\in I$, there is $j_i$ such that $M_i=M_{j_i}$. By Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal element $N=\oplus_{i\in I} M_i$. We can show that $N=\mathcal H$, because if not then pick $f\in N^{\perp}$ and $N\oplus \bigvee_{m,n = 0}^\infty \{A^n(A^*)^m f\}$ extends $N$. (Well, if we define $\oplus_{i\in I} M_i\le \oplus_{j\in J} M_j$ as the notation orignally means, i.e. the former is a linear subspace of the latter, the whole argument works as well.)
2. Normality hence spectrum is not important for this step. Just use the fact that given $A: \oplus_{i\in I} M_i\rightarrow \oplus_{i\in I} M_i$, then $\|A\|=\sup_i \|A|_{M_i}\|$.
3. This is a subtle point: In the theory of Hilbert spaces, we define $\oplus_{i\in I} M_i$ as the completion of the algebraic direct sum. More explicitly, $$\oplus_{i\in I} M_i =\{(f_i)|f_i\in M_i, \sum_{i\in I}\|f_i\|^2<\infty\}$$ With this in mind, it's easy to define $\oplus M_{h_n}$ as an operator on $L^2(X, \mu)$.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by $M_i$ is cyclic? Also, do you mean $N = \mathcal H$?

Comment: 1. Why does $N\oplus \bigvee_{m,n = 0}^\infty \{A^n(A^*)^m f\}$ extend $N$? Could you show more details? Not sure why $f\in N^\perp \implies \bigvee_{m,n = 0}^\infty \{A^n(A^*)^m f\} \subset N^\perp$.

Comment: $M_i$ is cyclic meaning it contains a cyclic vector $f$ of $A$. And yeah, I mean $N=\mathcal H$ (corrected). I don't know what more you want: it's clear that $N<N\oplus \cdots$ by our definition of $\le$. Because $N$ is both $A$-invariant and $A^*$-invariant, hence $N^{\perp}$ is also both $A$-invariant and $A^*$-invariant.

Comment: Thanks! 2. I agree with $\|A\|=\sup_i \|A|_{M_i}\|$, but why is $\|A\|=\|h\|_\infty$?

Comment: $\|h\|_{\infty}=\sup_i \|h_i\|_{\infty}$ also holds, and $\|A|_{M_i}\|=\|h_i\|_{\infty}$ holds because we are assuming the result holds for the cyclic case. (Sorry that I'm using $i$ rather than $n$ everywhere -- in fact, $\mathcal H$ is separable isn't used often).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $\|A|_{M_i}\|=\|h_i\|_{\infty}$ holds. Could you add more details? Are you saying that in the cyclic case, we have $\|A\| = \|h\|_\infty$? I had not seen that, so I wonder how.

Comment: Yes. Because in the cyclic case, you have established that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $M_h$ hence $\|A\|=\|M_h\|$, and it's a standard result that $\|M_h\|=\|h\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: One last question: are we saying that $L^2(X,\mu) = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty L^2(X_n,\mu_n)$? or just that they're *isomorphic* in some sense? I understand the construction of $L^2(X,\mu)$, but I am not able to relate it with (3) in your answer.

Comment: Well, technically it's an isomorphism. There is an obvious map: for each function $f$ over $X$, we can define the sequence $(f|_{X_n})$ in the (external) direct sum. Now it remains to show that $f$ is square integrable iff each $f|_{X_n}$ is square integrable and $\sum_{n}\|f|_{X_n}\|_2^2<\infty$.

Comment: I think this follows immediately, since $\int_X |f|^2\, d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n} |f|^2\, d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{X_n} \left|f\vert_{X_n} \right|^2\, d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{X_n} \left|f\vert_{X_n} \right|^2\, d\mu_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\|f\vert_{X_n} \right\|^2$

Comment: Apologies for bothering you again. To apply Zorn's lemma, you need every chain to have an upper bound. Given a (possibly infinite) chain of the collection $\{\oplus_{i\in I} M_i | M_i \text{ is cyclic and closed}\}$, what upper bound do you propose?

Comment: Just take the union $J$ of all the index sets $I$, and $\{\oplus_{j\in J} M_j\}$ is an upper bound.